# Angular JS - HTML Accordion breaking in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need some little help with some template I'm working on for my project.
I found this code for an accordion container on the internet:

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" and "show" classes when the user clicks on one of the "Section" buttons. The "active" class is used to add a background color to the current button when its belonging panel is open. The "show" class is used to open the specific accordion panel */
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the accordion panel when the user clicks on one of the buttons. This will show the panel content */
div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: "+"; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "-"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

It works fine, looks nice, exactly what I wanted. But when I try to do something like this:

```html
 <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
                    <button class="accordion">{{category.name}}</button>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p>{{category.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the tabs don't open anymore. I can't find the problem. Can anyone give me a solution to this?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you fix the snippets so they actually works? (Add references and styles)

Comment: Here is the example I used. http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp You have there all the code needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different approach to do this:

1. Add `ng-click` to the button to toggle the class `active` of him.
2. Change the `.show` selector to `button.active + div.panel` so you can change only the button class.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.categories = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    $scope.categories.push({
      name: 'cat' + i,
      description: 'description' + i
    });
  }
});

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

button.active + div.panel {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2>Animated Accordion</h2>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <button class="accordion" data-ng-click="category.active = !category.active" data-ng-class="{'active': category.active}">{{category.name}}</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>{{category.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked :d Thank you so much. Setting 'active' with ng-class was quite nice. Never thought that will solve the problem.

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('mycontroller',function($scope){
      $scope.categories = [{name:'Lorem ipsum...'},{name:'Lorem ipsum...'},{name:'Lorem ipsum...'}]

    });
```

```html
    <html ng-app='app'>
      <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body ng-controller='mycontroller'>
    <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
                            <button ng-class="accordion">{{category.name}}</button>
                            <div ng-class="panel">
                                <p>{{category.description}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div></body>
      </html>
```

Comment: I already have a module and a controller in my code. And a function that gets my categories from a backend. I don't think this is the problem